# What does division order mean in Rayleigh Fading?

Tags: matlab, modulation, demodulation, qpsk

So I'm just beginning to understand how Rayleigh Fading works and I'm trying to model some different modulation schemes with Rayleigh fading channels. I'm doing this on MATLAB where one of the necessary parameters is something called division order but this isn't really explained on the MATLAB documentation.

Having a little look around I saw it being mentioned that division order is degrees of freedom but then, on Wikipedia, it says that the Rayleigh Distribution is pretty much the chi distribution with two degrees of freedom. Can division order be degrees of freedom? If so, what does this actually mean in the context of Rayleigh Fading?

Comment: I can't seem to see any reference to division order in the documentation of the Rayleigh fading model. I assume you are talking about the "comm.rayleighchannel" fading object. Can you point to the function that needs division order in MATLABs documentation?

Comment: This is the link: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/berfading.html but this could be as this is calculating BER that it needs divorder?

Comment: @It's the diversity order. The number of different independent transmit-receive paths in the scheme. If you have $m$ transmit antennas and $n$ receive antennas then the diversity order is at most $mn$. It will equal exactly $mn$ if the antennas are well separated.

Comment: Thank you for the link, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's the diversity order. This is the number of independent transmit-receive paths in the communication scheme under consideration. If you have \$m\$ transmit antennas and \$n\$ receive antennas then the diversity order is at most \$mn\$. It can only equal exactly \$mn\$ if the antennas are adequately separated.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!